# Emploi de « se refuser »

Tags: usage, verbes-pronominaux

J'ai entendu quelqu'un dire à la radio :

> "Nous nous refusons..."

Je ne me rappelle ni la préposition (à ou de), ni le contexte, ni la suite du discours.
Même une collègue, professeure du français, a dû consulter le dictionnaire pour vérifier le sens de ce verbe pronominal.

*se refuser (à ou de ?)* n'est-il pas reconnu ? Est-ce un néologisme ? Peut-on l'employer ?

Comment: Ta collègue est native ? Parce que si elle est native ET prof de français, ne pas connaître cette formulation est assez inquiétant...

Comment: @LaurentS. Pas native. Elle est prof de l'anglais, français (FSE) et de l'allemand. Peut-être elle n'a pas bien compris ma question (je n'ai pas ni contexte, ni la suite...). Merci pour le commentaire.

Comment: De rien :-) Accessoirement on dit "Elle est prof d'anglais, français et allemand" , ou "Elle est prof d'anglais, de français et d'allemand" si on veut répéter le "de", mais jamais "prof de l'allemand" ou "prof de l'anglais". Enfin sauf si on veut parler de la prof d'un individu particulier qui serait anglais ou allemand, mais dans ce cas on ne parle pas de la matière et ca n'est pas le sens de votre phrase.

Comment: @LaurentS. et on met alors une majuscule: *Elle est prof de l'Anglais* mais on dira plutôt *C'est la prof de l'Anglais*.

Comment: Effectivement, je m'en suis rendu compte trop tard pour pouvoir éditer mon commentaire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voir [refuser](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/refuser) § II. B.

> − réfl. indir. Se refuser qqc.Se priver volontairement de quelque chose. Il est vrai qu'en fait de création religieuse les siècles sont portés à se calomnier eux-mêmes, et à se refuser le privilège qu'ils accordent libéralement aux âges reculés! (Renan,Avenir sc., 1890, p. 487).Il se refusa la douceur de baiser cette tempe que déjà ses lèvres effleuraient (Martin du G.,Thib., Mort père, 1929, p. 1350).

C'est une formule couramment employée (surtout dans le domaine politique).